# Which of the methods is more suitable to call object's algorithm to execute conversion?

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns

I have a strategy pattern with factories inside. I don't know how much architecture should be visible outside. Which of the method is more correct?

1.

```
converterStrategyContext.getStrategy(ProductConverterStrategy.class).convert(product, ShowProductDto.class)
```

2.

```
converterStrategyContext.getStrategy(ProductConverterStrategy.class).getFactory(ShowProductDtoFactory.class).convert(product)
```

3.

```
converterStrategyContext.convert(product, ShowProductDto.class)
```

Specifying fewer arguments means more operations inside methods and forces to store relational structures of strategies, factories and dto to which the object is to be converted

Here is pseudo model of architecture
[image]

Comment: It depends whether you want to reuse this in future and whole application architecture

Comment: Any added model will need own strategy and factories. I have to call these methods in every endpoint in my API. Number 2 requires least effort because i don't have to store structures of relations to find correct objects for conversion to a specific type of dto